# How http status code and status text look like?

Tags: java, http, request, http-status-codes

I want to know how exactly the code is tranfered. Does http send a integer code within some header? 
Is only the code sent or also the text variation like "Created"?

The use case of this is. A service want from my service to receive a response 201 with exactly this text case sensitive "Created". Do I even have power to effect the case of the status?

Comment: HTTP is a specification (i.e. a documented set of behaviours), so it doesn't "send" anything.  Various implementations of the spec do the sending, with varying levels of compliance to the spec.  Suggest you read the spec some, and maybe research whatever server you're using.

Comment: @Taylor ok, that was an mistake in the description. But the question does not becomes inccorect because of it.

Comment: [The HTTP specification, section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6) describes the format of an HTTP response.